# Django форма авторизации и регистрации на одной странице

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать форму авторизации и регистрации на одной странице, но не могу понять логику. Отдельные формы работают шикарно.

[image: Сама страница]

```
views.py

class LoginUser( LoginView):
    form_class = LoginUserForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

 

class RegisterUser( CreateView):
     form_class = RegisterUserForm
     template_name = 'registration/login.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('main')




forms.py

class RegisterUserForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
        }


class LoginUserForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Логин', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}))



urls.py

    path('registration/login/', RegisterUser.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('registration/login/', LoginUser.as_view(), name='login')



login.html

<div class = "ggo">
      <form class="form-signin"  method='POST'  action="{% url 'login' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="username">email</label>
          <input type="email" name="username" class="form-styling">
          <label for="password">пароль</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-styling">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
          <label for="checkbox" ><span class="ui"></span>Keep me signed in</label> 
          <button type="submit"  value='sign_in' >Войти</button>
      </form>

       <form class="form-signup" method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}" >
          {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="fullname">Имя</label>
          <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="name" placeholder=""/> 
          <label for="username">email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-styling">
          <label for="password">пароль</label>
          <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-styling">
          <label for="password">Повторите пароль</label>
          <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-styling">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
          <label for="checkbox" ><span class="ui"></span>Keep me signed in</label>  
          <button type="submit" value='sign_up'>Регистрация</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
    path('registration/login/', RegisterUser.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('registration/login/', LoginUser.as_view(), name='login')
```

Не сработает, так как Django будет искать view для URL'а по первому совпадению. В вашем случае, если хотите сделать 2 разные логики на одной странице с 2мя формами, то во `views.py` нужно создать класс, который будет учитывать оба поведения, и решать, какое из 2х необходимо, например, по наличию `"password2" in requests.POST`, что будет характерно только для формы регистрации.

Так же можно написать обертку, которая будет возвращать одну из `view` в зависимости от наличия того же поля в запросе, примерно так:

```py
# views.py
def login_or_reg(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'password2' in request.POST:
        return RegisterUser.as_view()(request)  # Не уверен, нужно ли передавать args и kwargs
    return LoginUser.as_view()(request)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(...., login_or_req, ...),
    ...
]
```

Но лучше сделать через Ajax или как описал @Anton Balmakov в своем ответе

Comment: есть кто в теме? на сколько хороша данная практика? Я ее пользую на автомате для нескольких форм на одной странице, но сомнения никак не покидают...

Comment: Огромная благодарность, все шикарно работает.

Comment: @Дмитрий через разделение явно лучше, более читабельнее, чем все в одном месте

Comment: Тут не спорю, но те формы что на скрине, это тестовые. По факту это все будет укомплектовано по красоте)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше будет сделать одно поле с логином и добавить рядом кнопку регистрация, которая будет
перенаправлять человека на форму с регистрацией.
urls.py

```
path('authorization/login/', LoginUser.as_view(), name='login')
path('registration/login/', RegisterUser.as_view(), name='register'),
```

views.py

```
class RegisterUser( CreateView):
     form_class = RegisterUserForm
     template_name = 'registration/registration.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('main')
```

registration.html

```
<form class="form-signup" method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}" >
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="fullname">Имя</label>
      <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="name" placeholder=""/> 
      <label for="username">email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-styling">
      <label for="password">пароль</label>
      <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-styling">
      <label for="password">Повторите пароль</label>
      <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-styling">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
      <label for="checkbox" ><span class="ui"></span>Keep me signed in</label>  
      <button type="submit" value='sign_up'>Регистрация</button>
  </form>
```

Если этот ответ вам помог, отметьте его правильным.
Хорошего дня!